# Does Neuroph Image Recognition Plugin correctly convert RGB images to Black/White?

Tags: java, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have a question regarding the `FractionRgbData` class of Neuroph ImageRecognition of Neuroph 2.6. I do not fully understand the implementation of the static `FractionRgbData.convertRgbInputToBinaryBlackAndWhite(double[] inputRGB)` method (see a copy of the method below). More specifically, I do not understand why the length of the input array is divided by 3 in the for-loop condition and the for-loop variable `i` is also incremented with 3 every iteration? I would think dividing the input array by 3 should be enough.

Note that this method is used in the [`ImageRecognitionHelper`](http://neuroph.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/neuroph/tags/neuroph-2.6/src/org/neuroph/contrib/imgrec/ImageRecognitionHelper.java?revision=1271&view=markup) class and this class shows that the `inputRGB` double comes from the `FractionRgbData.getFlattenedRgbValues()` which can be seen [here](http://neuroph.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/neuroph/tags/neuroph-2.6/src/org/neuroph/contrib/imgrec/FractionRgbData.java?revision=1271&view=markup). As far as I could understand the `inputRGB` double array contains the red, green and blue channel of the image one after another.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this implementation!

Thanks in advance,

Barry NL

```
/**
 * Converts image rgb data to binary black and white data
 * @param inputRGB flatten rgb data
 * @return binary black and white representation of image
 */
public static double[] convertRgbInputToBinaryBlackAndWhite(double[] inputRGB) {
    double inputBinary[]= new double[inputRGB.length/3];

    for(int i=0; i<inputRGB.length/3; i+=3) {
        if (inputRGB>0) inputBinary = 0;
            else inputBinary = 1;
    }

    return inputBinary;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Neuroph developer has answered the above question on the support forum of Neuroph. It can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neuroph/forums/forum/862858/topic/5247473).

In short, the developer says the implementation is incorrect and does not correctly convert to black/white.